# Mysql query in combination with join, group by, having and order by clause

Tags: mysql

```
$date = $this->db->select('crv.date')
            ->from('commodities com')
            ->where('com.id = ' . $row->id)
            ->join('curves crv', 'com.curve_id = crv.profile_id', 'left')
            ->group_by('crv.date')
            ->having('COUNT(DISTINCT crv.job_id) = ' . $nr_commodities)
            ->order_by('crv.date DESC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->get()->row();
```

I need to convert the above query in mysql :

I tried the following. but getting some syntax errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
select crv.date
from commodities com
  where com.id = 100
left join curves crv on com.curve_id = crv.profile_id
group by crv.date
  having COUNT(DISTINCT crv.job_id) = 4
order by crv.date DESC
           limit 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use,

```
select crv.date
from commodities com
left join curves crv on com.curve_id = crv.profile_id
where com.id = 100
group by crv.date
  having COUNT(DISTINCT crv.job_id) = 4
order by crv.date DESC
           limit 1
```